# Why is this question bad?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

[What make messages to Facebook page not delivered?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/124055/63572)

This question has 2 downvotes. I know only the voters know why they think it's bad, but if you are a voter, then why is that? I think the only reason is because it lacks research, but I have provided everything I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is because the question could be clearer.<sup>*</sup>
E.g. I only use Facebook from within a Windows browser, and some things strike me as unclear:

- *if you send a message*. From where/with what app?
- does the receiver really *accept*, or just *read*?
- *message to a page*?? Since when can you *send messages to a page*? Am I missing something here? You can only post to/on a page, I believe.
- What is the *Facebook Page* app? Do you mean the [Facebook Pages Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.pages.app)?

Some screenshots would have helped a lot to understand what you're asking.

<sup>* I notice many unclear questions on this SE site having downvotes without comments. My guess is there are people getting a bit fed up with dealing with unclear questions and they do not want to spend more time on those than a quick downvote.</sup>

Comment: We encourage people to leave comments. But then we end up with irate Askers arguing with commenters and, in some cases, trying to take revenge against them. That's made some people comment-shy. It could also just be a case where the voter thought the vote speaks for itself.

Comment: @Ooker If you mark this answer as 'correct', how about updating the question to make it clearer? ;-) That way you leave more valuable information for future readers (one of the main reasons these SE sites exist).

Answer (score 3):

> I know only the voters know why they think it's bad

This is, unfortunately, the crux of it. I'm sorry that someone didn't leave a comment as to how it could be improved.  I don't see much, if anything, wrong with the question.

The only thing that someone *might* take issue with (and again, I can't speak for the rationale of the voters) is that

> I wonder if the admin of the page has to accept it so that the status can change to Delivered. Is that correct?

could potentially only be answerable by Facebook themselves, and therefore, this is inviting speculation about their internal policies and business logic.

Comment: this makes me wonder: would a large portion of users of this site not really use with Facebook? Because if anyone uses it for a while should know that the admin of a page is different to the admin of Facebook. (I know you have emphasized many times that you are not sure about this, but just in case it's true)